# How to split data depending on the values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, split

In my project(Angular and  .net) there is a function to download the details of the courses followed by a particular student.Once the report is downloaded,the report will be visibe as below table in a excel sheet.

[image]

In my backend code(web api) in the provider class the relavant method for this download is as below.

```
public async Task<students> GetReport(string sId)
{
    var response = await dbAccess.GetCoursesForReport(sId);

    return studentReportMapper.Map(response);
}
```

what I receive for response is values in the  above table.

what I want to know is how can I modify the above method to split the Courses  **depending on the** **completed level**(level1,level2,level3).Because I want to show the details in seperate excel worksheets based on the levels that they have completed,when the report is downloaded.(In the above case in three different worksheets named as level1,level2 and level3)As now the report is downloading in a single worksheet.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question? I'm not sure what you're asking? You can pass a parameter, to filter by level completed. Or you can return a list of students, grouped by level completed. Also can you supply the model for `students`?

Comment: @Greg I have already implemented the model.the report is downloaded as the table above in a single excel sheet.The function works properly.What I want to do is to modify the function as mentioned above by splitting from the Level Completed.(Because if the student just clicks the download button,it will be downloaded as above table and if the user click on the checkbox for splitted report version,then the report has to be downloded in 3 worksheets based on each level)

Comment: [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) on completed level?

Comment: So it needs to be downloaded as a single file with 3 worksheets? If yes, then it needs to be done where you are constructing the excel file.

Comment: something like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZWphf?

Comment: @rissa No problem, if this helped you, you could help me out by upvoting some of my accepted answers. No obligation though! have a nice day

Comment: @JochemVanHespen In here, dotnetfiddle.net/XZWphf..If I want to return the item(instead of item.Code and so on..),which is an object(just as " return studentReportMapper.Map(response);" in the existing method).As I understood, I have to add to a list and do it.But I have no idea how can I do it or whether my assumption is correct.Can you please help  me out?I am new to c#.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Simply instead of console,log, i Have to write a return statement which returns the item object. without changing the return type of the method.Can You pleaase let me know how to do it.Thanks in advance!!!I have already upvoted the the helped answers.

Comment: can you try and adjust the dotnetfiddle with what you are trying to do and resent the link, so i can see? don't worry it if not works

Comment: @JochemVanHespen https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iq8AcK... Iam getting errors,I want to do something like this

Comment: @rissa https://dotnetfiddle.net/AVfnQO simplified some things

Comment: @JochemVanHespen thankyou... i referred this and also by considering my requirment,I implemented the method,but still I dont get the result as expected.Can you please look into this,and help me out if possible.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559854/how-can-i-display-my-response-according-to-the-grouped-product-categories-as-bel

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using LINQ

```
var levelOne = result.Where(x => x.Level == 1).ToList();
var levelTwo = result.Where(x => x.Level == 2).ToList();
var levelThree = result.Where(x => x.Level == 3).ToList();
```

Now, you will have to build your response with the lists and that's all.