# How can I display my response according to the grouped product categories as below in c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, arraylist, group-by

This is my method in the provider class

```
public async Task<List<ProductSummary>> GetProductDetails(string pId, bool isSplitVersion)
{
    var response = await dbAccess.GetProductDetailsReport(pId);

    List<ProductSummary> ProdList = new List<ProductSummary>();
    if (isSplitVersion)
    {

        var distinctProductCat = response.GroupBy(x => x.PRODUCT_CATEGORY);
        foreach (var productCategory in distinctProductCat)
        {

            foreach (var item in productCategory)
            {


                ProdList.Add(item);


            }
            return productReportMapper.Map(ProdList);

            


        }

    }
    return productReportMapper.Map(response);
    
}
```

when the isSplitVersion is true, products are grouped by the product category and will assign to distinctProductCat .(i.e category1,category2,category3)And I want to appear my response as below.(Response has to be separated by the product categories)

```
    {
    "Value": {
        "category1": [
            {
                ...
                "Product Name": "ABC",
                "Product Category": "category1"
                ...
            }
        ],


       "category2": [
            {
                 ...
                 "Product  Name": "EFG",
                 "Product Category": "category2"
                 ...
            },
            {
                 ...
                 "Product  Name": "XYZ",
                 "Product Category": "category2"
                 ...
            },
            {
                 ...
                 "Product  Name": "SDF",
                 "Product Category": "category2"
                 ...
            }
        ],
     "category3": [
            {
                 ...
                 "Product  Name": "BNV",
                 "Product Category": "category3"
                 ...
            },
            {
                  ...
                 "Product  Name": "DFG",
                 "Product Category": "category3"
                 ...
            }
        ]

    },
    "Formatters": [],
    "ContentTypes": [],
    "DeclaredType": null,
    "StatusCode": 200
}
```

From the method that I have implemented, I don't get the expected response. How Can I adjust my code in the provider class to get the response as above.(At present I get only category 1 in my reponse.I don't get category 2 and 3)

Any Help is Appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your classes pls?

Comment: @Serge I have lot of classes and so many interrelated methods in each class,Thats why I just posted the method that iam having the issue after debugging.As far as I understand,i am having the issue with the place of the return statement.Bcause it returns the all the items in the category 1 correctly, but wont loop to the category 2 and display its items in a new array.But I get all the distinct categories to the "distinctProductCat" variable after groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are going over your first `for loop` (`foreach (var productCategory in distinctProductCat)`)only once, cause you are returning just after the first run here - `return productReportMapper.Map(ProdList);`

It seems to me like you need `Dictionary<string, List<ProductSummary>>` and not `List<ProductSummary>`,
and I am not sure what happens inside `productReportMapper.Map()`, and if you need it at all, cause you did not add it, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
...
if (isSplitVersion)
{
   var distinctProductCat = response
      .GroupBy(x => x.PRODUCT_CATEGORY)
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());

   return productReportMapper.Map(distinctProductCat);
}
...
```

Comment: Hi I identified my mistake as you have mentioned.(yes it should be Dictionary<string,List<productSummary>>)edited my method as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606013/how-to-convert-below-dictionary-method-to-lookup-or-keyvalue-pair..